# Windows Essential Business Server

Tags: windows-server-essentials

We are currently going through the process of installing windows essential business server.  We successfully made it through the utility/planning of the servers with no issues.

Going through the setup process when running the environmental tools test, we receive this error code:

"An error occured when reading the name of the Active Directory FSMO role owner"

The domain controller is installed in a server 2003 environment with everything running smoothly.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any recommendations to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your FSMO roles aren't correctly defined.

Run a DCDIAG on your existing DC and see if you get errors regarding the roles.

If you do, then follow this article to seize them over to that current DC:  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;255504

Once the roles look correct (you can query for the roles using "netdom query fsmo" from the current DC and make sure the results return ok), then you should be able to proceed.

Here's a link about WEBS 2008 and FSMO roles:  http://blogs.technet.com/essentialbusinessserver/archive/2009/02/10/fsmo-role-distribution-for-different-windows-essential-business-server-deployment-scenarios.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys.  It turned out the Infrastructure Master role was on a separate domain controller and since we are only using one domain controller, it required that role to get seized.

That worked perfectly and we are now proceeding the next steps of our Essential Business Server!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do is to check in AD that the FSMO masters are showing up correctly. [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801) explains how to view their settings (its for Server 2003 but they are in the same place in 2008).
If this all comes back correctly then you would assume its an issue with the environment test, if your FSMO role servers are not identified correctly then you have issues to sort out.